# What does this RenderBox flutter error mean?

Tags: flutter

what does this error mean???

RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#3b443 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'

[image]
[image]
Here is the picture of the error

Comment: This error may be due to size of the widget. You may be wrapping a widget in wrong parent one. So, it would be better if you can share the code so we can help you correct it

Comment: also, try posting pictures of the error...that way its easier

Comment: [here is the link to my code][1]
The Stack widget in the return statement of the LayoutBuilder widget is the relevant error causing widget. You can find it in CardScrollHorizontalInsetLayout widget in the cardScrollWidget.dart file. 


  [1]: https://github.com/Sanmay-svg/CardScrollWidget.git

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when there is no parent widget providing a size constraint to the child. So try to include the widget on SizedBox and provide `height` and `width` property to it.

hope this is helpful!